# How to reduce np.array layers by one?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array which looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
               [[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]]])
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[10 11 12]
  [13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]]
```

Is there a simple way to transform it to this:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]]
```

**Edit**

With the help of Vinay I was able to do this:

```
ar = np.reshape(ar, (len(ar), -1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reshape method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
...                [[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]]])
>>> np.reshape(ar, (2,-1)) 

array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the data are not sorted to begin with you can use sort following the reshape as Vinay recommended.

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
               [[10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18]]])

ar = np.sort(np.reshape(ar, (2,9)))

print(ar)
```